# Как писать комментарии в телеграмм канале?

Tags: python, telegram

Недавно начал смотреть API телеграмма. Подскажите, какие есть библиотеки для того, чтобы от имени пользователя писать комментарии под постами в телеграмм канале? Логин и пароль пользователя есть

Comment: AIOGram,
python-telegram-bot,
Telepot,
Telegram Bot Service,
telebot,
twx.botapi,
pyTelegramBotAPI; это все библиотеки для создания бота, от имени бота легко писать. Telebot как по мне самый простой.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/Pyrogram/ Pyrogram -----------------------